# How to find angular velocity of a spherical object in spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

[image]
How angular velocity vector is calculated here?

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrix $S$ between body fixed coordinate system and inirtial coordinate system is:

$$S=\left[\hat{e}_\theta\,,\hat{e}_\phi\,,\hat{e}_r\right]=
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -\sin \left( \theta \right) &\cos \left( 
\theta \right) \cos \left( \varphi  \right) &\cos \left( \theta
 \right) \sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\ \cos
 \left( \theta \right) &\sin \left( \theta \right) \cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) &\sin \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( \varphi 
 \right) \\0&-\sin \left( \varphi  \right) &\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

and the components of the angular velocity vector given in inertial system are:

$$\vec{\Omega}=\left[0,0,\omega\right]^T$$

thus : the the components of the angular velocity vector given in body fixed  system are:

$$S^T\,\vec{\Omega}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ -\sin \left( \varphi 
 \right) \omega\\\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\omega\end {array} \right] 
$$

Answer (score -1):

The equation of motion in the rotating coordinate system is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate please how you have written angular velocity vector.